# Showing a frame of buttons after clicking on action uiitembar of navigation controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationitem, xamarin.ios

I want to create some thing like this:

[image]

When client click on the right button of the navigationcontorller (action button) a frame of buttons appear (like the image) and client select on of them. By selecting which one a new operation will done.

I'm a new on iphone and monotouch. is the frame a predefined component in iphone. if yes what is its name, and how i can use it. And if it is not a predefined component how i can create such a frame in my app?

Comment: You can use `UIActionSheet` for this......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an UIActionSheet.  There is a MonoTouch [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/MonoCatalogSample) that demonstrates how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

This is `UIActionSheet`. Here is a small example:

```
var sheet = new UIActionSheet ("");
sheet.AddButton ("Send email");
sheet.AddButton ("Send message");
sheet.AddButton ("Cancel");

sheet.CancelButtonIndex = 2;
sheet.Clicked += delegate(object sender, UIButtonEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ButtonIndex == 2)
    return;
};
sheet.ShowInView (this);
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. Unfortunately just can tick one reply as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in `ViewDidLoad` method,

```
UIBarButtonItem *arrow = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(showActionSheet)] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = arrow;
```

Write **showActionSheet** method's code and add `UIActionSheet *actionSheet in .h` file and give **@property** and **@synthesize**.

```
#pragma  mark - Button Methods

-(void)showActionSheet
{
    //  Here is code for UIActionSheet
         self.actionSheet= [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@" " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Hide Action" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Send email", @"Send message", nil];
         [self.actionSheet showInView:self.view];
         //self.actionSheet.tag=1;

}
```

Add delegate method of `UIActionSheet`

```
#pragma mark - UIActionSheet Delegate Methods

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
       if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
       // code for selected first Button.
    }
    else if(buttonIndex == 1)
    {
       // code for selected Second Button.      
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged with Monotouch.

Comment: @petert tagged with obj-C as well :/